# add to src in img with jquery

Tags: jquery, src

i need to change this :

```
<img src="example.jpg" alt="">
```

into this:

```
<img src="example.jpg?width=500" alt="">
```

with jquery, how can this be achived, because i don't want to overwrite the src, 
but just add that **?width=500** bit.

my code looks something like this in total:

```
<div class="img-wrap"> 
     <p><a href="link">Link to something</a></p>

     <img src="example.jpg" alt=""> 

</div>
```

**EDIT**
Okey, im sorry i did not specify, but i cannot make any changes to the img tag. 
The image is generated from the backend. the div, is the only thing i have any sort of power over.

Comment: And your JS code?

Comment: i haven't been able to figure out a way to add to it. that is my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
  $(".img-wrap p img")[0].src += "?width=500";
</script>

<div class="img-wrap">
  <p><a href="link">Link to something</a>
  </p>
  <img src="example.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: i can't add any id's to the img. it is generated from the backend.

Comment: this works :D You were the first to figure it out, so i give the solution here ^^

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can append string into src attribute.

### Edit:

If you only have control over the `div` then add add id to it.

```js
$("#click-me").on("click", function(){
    $("#img-wrapper>img").attr("src", $("#img-wrapper>img").attr("src") + "?s=20");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-wrap" id="img-wrapper"> 
     <p><a href="link">Link to something</a></p>
     <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7164662/38b30efb16b3d9eb8cc2737a872a79f0" alt="" /> 
     <button id="click-me" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i cannot add any ids or classes to the img tag, since it is genereted from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an image named `image1`

```
<img src="example.jpg" alt="" id="image1">
```

Use

```
$('#image1').attr('src') = $('img').attr('src') + '?width=500' ;
```

This will not overwrite the img `src`, it will just append `?width=500` to the existing attribute value.

Comment: this would chose every single img, wouldn't it ?

Comment: i cannot add any ids or classes to the image. The image tag is genereted by the backend system.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="img-wrap"> 
 <p><a href="link">Link to something</a></p>
 <img src="example.jpg" id="targetImage " alt=""> 
</div>
```

add id for the image to select in the jquery and using the attr u can add the text to the image src like below

```
var img= $("#targetImage");
img.attr("src", img.attr("src")+"?width=500");
```

Comment: i cannot add any ids or classes to the image. The image tag is generated by the backend system.

Comment: oh alright...then wait...let me think of another solution

Comment: @andrelange91 even u can select the img by simply giving the $('img').attr("src","img.attr("src")+"?width=500")

Comment: @andrelange91 do u have permission to create id on the div?

Comment: the image is generated from the backend, by the user, so if the div "img-wrap" has an image, it should add the ?width=500 to the src.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#img-wrap img:first").attr('src', img.attr("src")+"?width=500");
```

with out id and class name for the image you can select with the help of upper DOC element classes